# Adding type to a document uploaded in Alfresco through behaviour

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to associate a document type to xz:xylo, whenever a document is uploaded in a particular workspace of Alfresco, it should get attached to a type which I defined in xylomodel.xml.

I am trying to achieve this via Alfresco behaviour as procceding via Share has some limitation for my requirement.

Can anyone please correct me if the code attached is syntactically correct and I am approaching correctly.

```
enter code here
```

public class ApplyXyloAspect implements NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy {`

```
private NodeService nodeService;
private PolicyComponent policyComponent;
// Behaviours
private Behaviour onCreateNode;
     }
/**
  ^When a document of type @XyloCmsType(name = "X:xz:Xylo") is created than aspects from xyloModel.xml
  ^needs to be applied
 */
public void init() {
    // Create behaviours
    if workspace=workspace://SpacesStore/973e1b8d-bf61-8196-3278-fbbf0b4375gg
       org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies this.onCreateNode = new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateNode", NotificationFrequency.FIRST_EVENT);
    // Bind behaviours to node policies
    this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(Qname.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onCreateNode"),
        Qname.createQName(XYLO.NAMESPACE_XYLO_CONTENT_MODEL, XYLO.TYPE_xz_xyloModel),
        this.onCreateNode
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your requirements you might be better off achieving this through [Folder Rules](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/rule-actions.html).

If folder rules are not adequate, or if I'm misunderstanding your use of the very specific NodeRef of `workspace://SpacesStore/973e1b8d-bf61-8196-3278-fbbf0b4375gg` then I would just check in the onCreateNode method if the created node's parent matches that NodeRef, rather than trying to check in the init method.

so in your init method you would just do something like this:

```
this.onCreateNode = new JavaBehaviour(this, "onCreateNode", Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.FIRST_EVENT);
        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME, Qname.createQName(XYLO.NAMESPACE_XYLO_CONTENT_MODEL, XYLO.TYPE_xz_xyloModel), this.onCreateNode);
```

And then just check if the node is a child of the node you're trying to have be the parent, in this case you said it would be `workspace://SpacesStore/973e1b8d-bf61-8196-3278-fbbf0b4375gg`.

So the onCreateNode method would look something like this.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssociationRef){
        NodeRef idealParentNodeRef = new NodeRef("workspace://SpacesStore/973e1b8d-bf61-8196-3278-fbbf0b4375gg");
        NodeRef nodeRef = childAssociationRef.getChildRef();
        NodeRef parentRef = childAssociationRef.getParentRef();
        //First double check and make sure all the nodes exist.
        if(nodeService.exists(nodeRef) && nodeService.exists(parentRef) && nodeService.exists(idealParentNodeRef)){
            //then check if the parentRef and the idealParentNodeRef match
            if(parentRef.equals(idealParentNodeRef)){
                nodeService.addAspect(nodeRef, /*QName of the Aspect you want to add*/);
            }
        }
    }
```

If you know for a fact the node/workspace you're uploading to will be very specific every time you could just do this, though I would probably also suggest throwing in some error handling, logging, etc. but this would get you started at least.

**Note** that, generally, you shouldn't necessarily expect the NodeRef to stay the same every time, granted, I'm just showing you what you *could* do based on the information from your post rather than what you *should* do (which would be finding some other way to reference the NodeRef/workspace you're trying to use, and going on from there, depending on whether that NodeRef/workspace is a Folder or Site, or something else).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply and help. My code is struck at if(nodeService.exists(nodeRef) && nodeService.exists(parentRef) && nodeService.exists(idealParentNodeRef)) ...stating null point exception. IS there any declaration I need to do to use nodeService?

Comment: Yes, much like the policyComponent you will need to reference the NodeService bean for that property (Make sure you have the setter method made for it as well) in the context file where you define the bean for that class.

Comment: Hi - looks like my code is error free now but when I try to invoke the method onAddDocument then its not triggering and my control never comes to this method.                                                                                getPolicyComponent().bindClassBehaviour(NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME, ContentModel.TYPE_XYLO,
                    new JavaBehaviour(this, "onAddDocument", Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.FIRST_EVENT));

Comment: Check the bean definition and make sure you set the init-method attribute to your init method in the class.